# Passing data to Web Service getting - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, web-services, fetch, internal-server-error

I have an issue with fetching and passing data to ASP.NET web service from ReactJS.

Other fetch function is working when only getting data from the database.
Why am I getting these errors ? what am I doing here wrong ?
I believe its something in my `signUp` fetch function.

That response I think is that the fetch can't read the response from the server -

> ```
> main.chunk.js:2417 POST http://localhost:50496/WebService.asmx/SignUp 500 (Internal Server Error)
> ```

> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 0  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
> ```

**ReactJS**

```
userData = {
    fName: 'some',
    lName: 'two one',
    email: 'someonw@gmail.com',
    password: 'se123456'  }
```

My fetch function in ReactJs  -

```
   const signUp = (signUpData) => {
 
    let data = {
      firstName: signUpData.fName,
      lastName: signUpData.lName,
      emailAddress: signUpData.email,
      password: signUpData.password,
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:50496/WebService.asmx/SignUp', {
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then(
        (xml) =>
          new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')
            .documentElement.firstChild.textContent
      )
      .then((jsonStr) => JSON.parse(jsonStr))
      .then((userData) => {
        if (userData.d  && userData.d.length > 0) {
          setUser(userData);
        } else {
          console.log('error no data');
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

Error from Chrome  -

> System.InvalidOperationException: Missing parameter : firstName.
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()

`SignUp` WebMethod is working in the WebService.

```
[WebMethod]
public string SignUp(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string password)
{
   return BLL.SignUp(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, password);
}
```

[image: Chrome - Network - Header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found What I needed to do, 
another error was -

> InvalidOperationException: Only web services with the [ScriptService]
> attribute in the class definition can be read from a script.

So I added to **WebService.cs** the Attribute Class`[ScriptService]`

```
 [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
 [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
 [ScriptService]
```

And Since this completely eliminates the need to parse XML as you must when using standard SOAP (Simple Object Access Protocol) web services,
 I removed this code lines -

```
.then((response) => response.text())
      .then(
        (xml) =>
          new window.DOMParser().parseFromString(xml, 'text/xml')
             .documentElement.firstChild.textContent 
      )
      .then((jsonStr) => JSON.parse(jsonStr))
```

And changed to this -

```
 .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((userData) => {
    if (userData.d && userData.d.length > 0) {
      let user = JSON.parse(userData.d);
      setUserData(user);
      }
```